# javascript event for observing when user typed text in contenteditable div and text get a blue highlight?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, contenteditable

I am implementing an editor using contenteditable div on UIWebView。when typing some random English characters, the background of those characters may become blue, and there will be some suggested word on the iOS keyboard:

[image: a busy cat]

I want to know:

1. Is there any javascript event I can listen to for observing the moment when those text is highlight?
2. Is there any way I can programmatically remove those highlights?

I have try to find suitable events in mdn documents, but nighter `selection`, `compositionstart`, `compositionupdate`, `compositionend` got called when text got blue highlight。

If there is no such javascript event, I would appreciate any suggestion for implementing an observing function.

thanks in  advance.

Comment: what event exactly do you want? ELaborate

Comment: @Nagaraju: Maybe I did not express my question clear enough. My Question was: which js event will be fire when the blue background show up as in the screenshot? ＩIf I know that I can do some post action when the event fired: $(myEditableDIV).on('textHighlightShowUpEvent', function(e) {
   // my post action, something like removing the highlight and implementing my word suggestion algorithm.
})。

Comment: tell me how the highlight is happening, are you highlighting them?

Comment: @Nagaraju: plz see this short video: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1UAFbO4Yku2m55pyoInTSYsGT6SDEL5IJ  It was a simple contentediable div loaded by iOS's UIWebView. The source of the html file can be found here: https://gist.github.com/ctwdtw/aa012e3057fece4d7498cd03a0c3b289